# Autofac Resolve from new lifetimeScope

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

Is there any way to tell Autofac to resolve a component from a new lifetime scope?

Meaning:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<Layer1>().As<ILayer1>().SingleInstance(); 
containerBuilder.RegisterType<Layer2>().As<ILayer2>().SingleInstance(); 
containerBuilder.RegisterType<Layer3>().As<ILayer3>().SingleInstance(); 
containerBuilder.RegisterType<MyContainer>().As<IContainer>().SingleInstance(); 
containerBuilder.RegisterType<Layer1>().As<ILayer>().SingleInstance(); 
containerBuilder.RegisterType<IRepository<Folder>>().As<FoldersRepository>().InstancePerDependency();
```

MyContainer takes all the Layers in his ctor.
Though I want Layer1 for example to be resolved in a new lifetimeScope. Is there a way to do so by specifying it in the registration instead of resolving it manually from a new life time scope??

```
using (var myLifeTimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope()) 
{ 
   var myLayer1=mylLifeTimeScope.Resolve<ILayer>(); 
} 

using (var myLifeTimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope()) 
{ 
   var container=mylLifeTimeScope.Resolve<IContainer>(); 
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do anything like that in your registration code. But in your example it does not really matter, because you would get the same instance of layers every time, as they all are registered as `SingleInstance()`

Comment: Please see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471559/autofac-perlifetimescope-vs-perrequest-in-web-applications/35476918?noredirect=1#comment58661206_35476918

Still having difficulties understanding how to manage there